# Error with client/contracts using API's functionality

Tags: ibm-api-management, apiman

We are getting the errors while working with the client/contracts when managing it with API’s

**Here is the scenario that we are facing:**

We have an Api that we have created and added a contract to it:

Upon checking of API Contract, we are getting the following error:

Contract API Error

[image]

But the same with given endpoint is working fine while working it with key/client app using programmatically in our application, But when we are checking it with client's menu,

White Page Error

[image]

we are having totally blank white page ahead

Answer (score 1):

Bug reports relating to Apiman should be filed in the "issues" section on the GitHub Apiman repository: https://github.com/apiman/apiman

The 'discussions' section is also available for more general help questions and topics if you are struggling with your configuration or migration (i.e. not really within Stack Overflow's area).

*(Disclosure: I am Apiman's principal maintainer).*

Comment: Thanks for the support, thought the ticket is already opened there too